How to search Confluence pages by the date of the last comment?
I am working on a Confluence project and need to find pages based on the date of the last comment, rather than the creation date. I’ve tried using the DateRangeQuery, but it seems to search based on the creation date. Here’s a snippet of my code:
    import java.time.ZoneId
    import java.time.ZoneOffset
    import java.time.LocalDateTime
    import java.time.LocalDate
    import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.query.LabelQuery
    import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
    import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.PageManager
    import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.*;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.sort.CreatedSort;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.AbstractPage;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.query.BooleanQuery;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.query.TermQuery;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.search.searchers.query.*;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.SearchQuery;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.query.DateRangeQuery
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.confluence.utils.CQLSearchUtils
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.confluence.utils.CQLSearch
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl
    
            SearchManager searchManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SearchManager)
            PageManager pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager)
    
            Set<SearchQuery> buildQuery = new HashSet<>();
            SearchSort sort = new CreatedSort(SearchSort.Order.DESCENDING);
    
            LocalDate nowMinusOneWeek = LocalDate.now().minusWeeks(1);
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);

            Set<SearchQuery> dateQuerySet = new HashSet<>();
                Date startDate = Date.from(nowMinusOneWeek.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            Date endDate = Date.from(now.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            
            DateRangeQuery dateRangeQuery = new DateRangeQuery(startDate, endDate, true, true, "lastmodified")
    
            dateQuerySet.add(dateRangeQuery);
            dateQuerySet.add(new TermQuery("type", "comment"));
    
             //dateQuerySet.add(new LabelQuery("2023-09-01")); 
           
            SearchQuery dateQuery = BooleanQuery.composeOrQuery(dateQuerySet);
            buildQuery.add(dateQuery)
            SearchQuery composedQuery = BooleanQuery.composeAndQuery(buildQuery);
            ContentSearch contentSearch = new ContentSearch(
                composedQuery, 
                sort, 
                null, 
                0, 
                500
            );
    
            SearchResults searchResults = searchManager.search(contentSearch);
            List<AbstractPage> pages = new ArrayList<>();

            log.warn(pages.size())

